# How to identify the same user in different sites in stack data dump?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump

I'm wondering if there exists a way to identify the same user across different stack exchange sites. Like Id are unique for user across this sites? If not, is there some data like information that user logged in using Stack Exchange account and which account?
I really want to identify which users are using which sites to check:
 a) common part of different sites by knowing how many users they share, 
 b) examine flow of people between different fields of science and technology by examining mix of sites data, tags and activity
 c) and much more...

Answer (score 3):

The User element has a networkId attribute, which is the network-wide unique ID for the user. If you have dumps from multiple sites, match those up to find the same user on both sites  (where a user has accounts on both).